# WCF REST Service Template 40 and Entity Framework in JSON format returning empty response

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf, rest, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to build a Rest JSON service with the WCF REST Service Template 40 and Entity FrameWork.

When I try to create regular object and return it everything works fine and I get back JSON response (GetEvent Method)

When I try to return object that called from entity framework in XML format everything works fine (GetEvent3 Method)

But When i try to return Json response from object that was called from entity framework I get empty response (GetEvent2 Method)

Any idea why?

This is my code:

```
    [DataContract]
public class Event
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Event Name")]
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Event StartTime")]
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime StartTime;

    [Display(Name = "Event EndTime")]
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime EndTime;
}




[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetEvent", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Event GetEvent();

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetEvent2", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Event GetEvent2();

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetEvent3", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    Event GetEvent3();
}



[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    private readonly EventsDB _db = new EventsDB();

    // This method return good response in Json format
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetEvent", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Event GetEvent()
    {
        return new Event
        {
            ID = 1,
            Name = "A vs. B",
            StartTime = new DateTime(2012, 4, 10, 18, 00, 00),
            EndTime = new DateTime(2012, 4, 11, 18, 00, 00),
        };
    }

    // This method return no response
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetEvent2", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Event GetEvent2()
    {
        Event e = _db.Events.ToList()[0];
        return e;
    }

    // This method return good response in XML format
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetEvent3", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    public Event GetEvent3()
    {
        Event e = _db.Events.ToList()[0];
        return e;
    }
}
```

Web.Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EventsDB"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=EventsDB"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfRestService3.Service1">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:50235/service1"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="WcfRestService3.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>


</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug GetEvent2 method on what is retrieved from your database before being returned. Also check if you have lazy loading set to true and try to set lazy loading to false and load your Event object as JSON data contract serializer doesnt serialize entity framework objects with internal collections.

Comment: More info here : http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/354859/entity-framework-entitycollection-and-datacontractjsonserializer (or) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/9bff1c80-41e3-483a-8762-304efa630328

Comment: @Fulvio : Would try to check my suggestions given in my answer with your code ? Whether it works or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using asp.net mvc for your rest services? It's really straightforward, safe and quick. It's the kind of thing that for sure makes your life better. A service like the one you're posting here can be complete in around 20 minutes with no more than 10 lines of code. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the `[OperationContract]` attribute for `GetEvent2` method ?
I can see that the attribute is mentioned in the "Example" section @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webgetattribute.responseformat%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

**EDIT :** Your `GetEvent` method too has a `[OperationContract]` attribute applied, and per your description it works ?

Comment: All is fine. In WCF 4 REST OperationContract is not needed when WebGet or WebInvoke attributs are used